# Xubuntu: Unable to bind arbitrary shortcut keys

Tags: shortcut-keys, xubuntu, xfce

I used to be able to bind any arbitrary shortcut key to launching external applications; in particular, I used to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>hjkl</kbd> to a small utility which moves the mouse cursor around.

However, a while back, this stopped working, as now it only seems to allow binding shortcut keys to a single modifier at a time; pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> binds the action to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, for example.  If I manually edit my key bindings in the associated config file, the bindings simply do not work.

The one exception to the single-modifier shortcuts seems to be that you can bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>(anything)</kbd> to a separate shortcut; however, the purpose of this configuration is to improve my workstation ergonomics, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>hjkl</kbd> are somewhat more cumbersome to press.

Short of completely switching window managers, is there some way to get xfwm to recognize keyboard shortcuts formed from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>?

Comment: Hmm, I can confirm this issue using `Xfce 4.10`. This seems like a  bug; did you try to report it upstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `Xfce 4.10` and has been [reported here](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8744). The bug seems to have been fixed in GIT master, so the future `4.12` release shouldn't be affected by this issue. A bugfix release for `4.10` may or may not happen.